# Issue in connecting jsp with mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, jsp

This code while executing , is giving exception message but the same code while running in  java is working properly without any errors and exceptions.

The following code is writen in java and is working properly but the same logic is not working in jsp.

```
import com.mongodb.*;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import org.bson.Document;
import java.util.*;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCursor;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;
import com.mongodb.client.result.DeleteResult;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Updates.*;
import com.mongodb.client.result.UpdateResult;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class TestMongo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = "Ram";
        long ph = 7077330520L;
        String email = "DB@gmail.com";
        String password = "qwerty";
        String city = "BBSR";

        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");

        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("user");
        collection.drop();
        Document doc = new Document("name", name)
                .append("ph", ph)
                .append("email", email)
                .append("password",password)
                .append("city", city);

        collection.insertOne(doc);

        MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find().iterator();

        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            //if (cursor.next().getInteger("age") == 20)
                System.out.println(cursor.next());
        }
    }
}
```

[image: JSP CODE]

```
[![<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page import ="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page import ="java.util.Set" %>
<%@ page import="com.mongodb.*" %>
<%@ page import="com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase" %>
<%@ page import="org.bson.Document" %>
<%@ page import="com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection" %>

<%
    String name = "Ram";
    long ph = 7077330520L;
    String email = "DB@gmail.com";
    String password = "qwerty";
    String city = "BBSR";

    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");

    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("user");
    collection.drop();
    Document doc = new Document("name", name)
            .append("ph", ph)
            .append("email", email)
            .append("password",password)
            .append("city", city);

    collection.insertOne(doc);
%>][1]][1]
```

Comment: your JSP probably didn't compiled, surrond code with try catch (Trowable e) and see what's the error

Comment: Still , same error

Comment: your file isn't compiling, maybe mongodb jars are missing?

Answer (score 1):

```
    With mongo-java-driver-2.10.1.jar present in your build path surely below code works

    <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
    <%@ page import ="java.util.List" %>
    <%@ page import ="java.util.Set" %>
    <%@ page import="com.mongodb.*" %>
    <%@ page import="com.mongodb.DB" %>
    <%@ page import="org.json.JSONObject" %>
    <%@ page import="com.mongodb.DBCollection" %>


    <%
        String name = "Ram";
        long ph = 7077330520L;
        String email = "DB@gmail.com";
        String password = "qwerty";
        String city = "BBSR";

        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        DB database = mongoClient.getDB("test");

        DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("user");
        //collection.drop();
        BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
        document.put("name", name);
        document.put("ph", ph);
        document.put("email", email);
        document.put("password",password);
        document.put("city", city);

        collection.insert(document);
    %>
After inserting I have tested as well 
> db.user.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59549f53a5653b5b4303004f"),
        "name" : "Ram",
        "ph" : NumberLong("7077330520"),
        "email" : "DB@gmail.com",
        "password" : "qwerty",
        "city" : "BBSR"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59549fbda5653b5b43030050"),
        "name" : "Ram",
        "ph" : NumberLong("7077330520"),
        "email" : "DB@gmail.com",
        "password" : "qwerty",
        "city" : "BBSR"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59549feaa5653b5b43030051"),
        "name" : "Ram",
        "ph" : NumberLong("7077330520"),
        "email" : "DB@gmail.com",
        "password" : "qwerty",
        "city" : "BBSR"
}
>  As I executed many times, number of rows inserted 3 times.
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you really want to go with new driver , you need to have that in your build path and first all compilation errors must be removed. Compilation errors are marked in red color and can be easily found out from eclipse editor

Comment: Actually I am using IntelliJ and already included mongo jar file in external libraries but still the same result

Comment: Ok, just have simple jsp page without mongo stuff. if that works fine, no issues with ordinary jsp. Include line by line your mongo code. Hope you can check out errors in intellij. Like that can finetune the code. The code which I have given worked fine in eclipse web project . Can you please try that

Comment: yes I have tried it already. Normally JSP is working perfectly but when am using mongo its giving above mentioned exception. Is there any issue with the tomcat server 9.0 . (am using mongo3.4 jar file and have tried the same with mongo2.10 and 2.13 without any success).

Comment: should I try JBOSS

Comment: I am using Tomcat7.0 and by just adding the jar and using the above given code in jsp, no issues. But when I use code like MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test"); after adding the jar, it throws error. So changing web server does not resolve issues. Instead refine the mongo code according to the appropriate jar

Comment: Yes for different jars, defination pattern is different  and i have tried all those according to their documentation . Still can you give some light to -> Http Sttus [500]- [internal server error]

Comment: Plainly start a server and hope that is success. Then try with ordinary jsp page without mongo concepts. Check are you getting internal server there and if it is there, check for error logs. With mongo alone, the issues means line by line adding of code will help